# Sanity GROQ: order results by the value of a referenced field

Tags: sanity, groq

I have the document type `celeb`. And the document type `fact`. Each `fact` references a `celeb`. I want to list `celebs` ordered by their most recently updated `facts`. So the `celeb` which has just had a `fact` added about them would show up at the top.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Alexander Staubo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632555/alexander-staubo) in the Sanity help channel on Slack

> Something like:
>
> ```
> *[_type == "celeb"] {
>  _id,
>  name,
>  "latestFact": *[_type == "fact" && celeb._ref == ^._id] | order(_updatedAt desc)[0]
> }
>  | order(latestFact._updatedAt desc)
> ```
>
> This assumes that each fact has a field called celeb which is a ref to the celeb document.
>
> For each celeb, it finds the latest fact. At the end, it sorts all the celebs by the date.